# Changing the Indices of a 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I change the way a spot in a Java 2D array is accessed? I need the bottom left spot in an n x n array to be (0,0). So if I were modifying the bottom left number in matrix, I'd call [0][0] instead of [2][1]

Comment: what ? ask your question clear please

Comment: You can do `matrix[rowLength - 1 - i][j]`. Change `i and j` normally like `matrix[i][j]`

Comment: Learn and use the concepts of OO. Encapsulate your 2D array into a class and provide methods to access the elements as you like.